# Would a NSDictionary with thousands of objects be slow?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm starting to integrate my app's data with a web service, which requires a syncID for each object in the core data store. My objects already have an id attribute, but this relates to files stored using the same id, and so changing this isn't an option as things could go wrong. I'm also not comfortable changing the core data store, as my app already has a shipping version I've had problems with this in the past.

It seems the most ideal solution is a dictionary which contains a bunch of NSString keys and NSString objects. This could run into the thousands, given the size of each user's core data store.

Would an NSDictionary of this size be slow, or a problem? Would it be able to save to NSUserDefaults without taking too long?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.  It will probably not be slow.  But then again, who knows?  Write the application and profile.  You can always switch to something like Kyoto Cabinet or SQLite later on.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not a serious persistent store option you should ever consider.

Comment: Probably not an issue with records in the thousands, just keep in mind that when using an allocated object like NSDictionary, your app is storing that data in the device's RAM. If it's large enough, you'll probably see performance issues (if not a memory warning) but you can check that with profiling.

Comment: In addition, if it is a mobile machine, power consumption might be a concern, but you really need to just build then measure

Answer (score 4):

Foundation classes are quite capable and pretty well engineered in their implementations. 
It depends what really goes into the dictionaries and what you do with it.

You should really try something then measure then optimize if needed.

Comment: I should update this to say, by definition keys in NSDictionary need to implement the hash method. The keys already need to be unique. By using NSString kinds of objects you are getting a pretty fast hash so you should be fine. If you find you are not fine, then start optimizing and looking for faster solutions. Thousands of objects are no big deal in a modern Objective-C application.